# Clustering in Elasticsearch

Tags: cluster-computing, elasticsearch

I have implemented clustering using Elasticsearch. ElasticHead UI displays detected nodes.
However I am not sure how it works. Any one could please provide me a link/direction that shows how clustering works with elasticsearch?

Comment: If I google for "elasticsearch clustering" I get a bunch of links telling you exactly how it works.

Comment: @skaffman: Yes.. but none explains how it works when some node is down. what happens if master node is down

Comment: By "clustering" you mean text or statistical clustering or elasticserach node cluster? 
Do you need to know how to start using elasticsearch or you have specific problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ElasticSearch uses multicasting to see if there are other nodes with same cluster name  present in the network.
If there is such a node it connects to it.
It shares it data with it depending upon the shard configuration.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/modules/discovery/zen.html

Read the above to get the full idea